# C#: Capture multiple image and Save in same folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-capture, savefiledialog

Currently my code can able to do capture image and saved in defined location but if i try the same in second time image is overwrite so if same file name present in that folder, we have to change name of file dynamically.
How can I do that ?

Present screen capturing code is:

```
private void CaptureMyScreen()
{
    try
    {
        //Creating a new Bitmap object
        Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(1024, 768, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        //Creating a Rectangle object which will capture our Current Screen
        Rectangle captureRectangle = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;

        //Creating a New Graphics Object
        Graphics captureGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(captureBitmap);

        //Copying Image from The Screen
        captureGraphics.CopyFromScreen(captureRectangle.Left, captureRectangle.Top, 0, 0, captureRectangle.Size);

        //Saving the Image File (I am here Saving it in My D drive).
        captureBitmap.Save(@"D:\Capture.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        //Displaying the Successfull Result

        MessageBox.Show("Screen Captured");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, never hard code the path and file name in your cs file. Try appending a GUID to the filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use GUID to get unique name for every capture file. Something like

```
string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
captureBitmap.Save(@"D:\Capture-" + guid + ".jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

or, use current date and time for that, like this:

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
captureBitmap.Save(@"D:\Capture-" + timestamp + ".jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```